# How to query StockTracker java database

Tags: java, database

I have been trying to figure out how to query a java database but all I seem to run into are sql articles.  As you can probably see from my history I am very new to Java and probably not very good at it.  I need to list the user’s ID, first name, and last name followed by their stocks, including both the stock symbol and stock description ( name).  This needs to be done for all users.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.awt.BorderLayout.*;              // updated for v5.0
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;            // updated for v5.0

class StockTracker extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener, Activator, STAction
{
String stockSymbol;
StockTrackerDB db;
User user = null;

JTextField jtfStockSymbol;
JButton jbtAddStock,jbtDelStock,jbtLogout;
JButton jbtAddUser,jbtDelUser,jbtUpdUser,jbtListUsers;
JComboBox jcbStockList;
Activator caller;

public StockTracker(User currentUser, Activator callerObj,StockTrackerDB dbc)
                            throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
    super("Stock Tracker"); // call super (JFrame) constructor

    int width = 0; //330;
    int height = 0; //370;
    user = currentUser;
    caller = callerObj;     // save reference to caller object
    db = dbc;               // save reference to database (access class)

    // Define components for panel 1
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("User: "+user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName());
    jbtLogout = new JButton("Log out");

    JPanel p1= new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p1.add(label1, WEST);               // updated for v5.0
    p1.add(jbtLogout, EAST);            // updated for v5.0

    jbtAddStock = new JButton("Add Stock");
    jbtDelStock = new JButton("Delete Stock");
    jtfStockSymbol = new JTextField(4);
    jcbStockList = new JComboBox();
    buildStockList();

    JPanel p2= new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,5,5)); // rows, cols, hgap, vgap
    p2.add(jbtAddStock);
    p2.add(jtfStockSymbol);
    p2.add(jbtDelStock);
    p2.add(jcbStockList);
    p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Stock Holdings"));

    // Define components for panel 3
    jbtAddUser = new JButton("Add new user");
    jbtDelUser = new JButton("Delete user");
    jbtUpdUser = new JButton("Update user");
    jbtListUsers = new JButton("List users");

    // Use nested panels for positioning
    JPanel p4= new JPanel();
    p4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p4.add(p1,NORTH);                   // updated for v5.0
    p4.add(p2,CENTER);                  // updated for v5.0

    if(user.isAdmin())
    {
        JPanel p3= new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5)); // rows, cols, hgap, vgap
        p3.add(jbtAddUser);
        p3.add(jbtUpdUser);
        p3.add(jbtDelUser);
        p3.add(jbtListUsers);
        p3.setBorder(new TitledBorder("User Maintenance"));
        p4.add(p3,SOUTH);               // updated for v5.0
    }

    JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p5.add(p4, WEST);                   // updated for v5.0
    JPanel p6 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
    p6.add(p5, EAST);                   // updated for v5.0

    setContentPane(p6);

    // Register listeners
    addWindowListener(this);

    jbtLogout.addActionListener(this);

    jbtAddStock.addActionListener(this);
    jbtDelStock.addActionListener(this);
    jcbStockList.addActionListener(this);

    jbtAddUser.addActionListener(this);
    jbtUpdUser.addActionListener(this);
    jbtDelUser.addActionListener(this);
    jbtListUsers.addActionListener(this);


    // Prepare for display
    pack();
    if( width < getWidth())             // prevent setting width too small
       width = getWidth();
    if(height < getHeight())            // prevent setting height too small
        height = getHeight();
    centerOnScreen(width, height);
    jtfStockSymbol.setText("");
    jtfStockSymbol.requestFocus();
   }

public void centerOnScreen(int width, int height)
{
  int top, left, x, y;

  // Get the screen dimension
  Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

  // Determine the location for the top left corner of the frame
  x = (screenSize.width - width)/2;
  y = (screenSize.height - height)/2;
  left = (x < 0) ? 0 : x;
  top = (y < 0) ? 0 : y;

  this.setBounds(left, top, width, height);
}

private boolean stockInList(String stockSymbol)
{
    boolean inList = false;
    int numItems;

    numItems = jcbStockList.getItemCount();

    stockSymbol.trim(); // remove any leading, trailing whitespace

    if(numItems > 0) // at least one entry is in list
        for(int i=0; i < numItems && !inList; ++i)
            if(stockSymbol.equals((String)jcbStockList.getItemAt(i)))
                inList = true;

    return inList;
}

private void addToStockList(String stockSymbol)
{
    int count = jcbStockList.getItemCount();
    int index = 0;

    if(!stockInList(stockSymbol))
    {
        if(count > 0)
           while( index < count
               && stockSymbol.compareTo( (String)jcbStockList.getItemAt(index) ) >= 0)
             ++index;

        jcbStockList.insertItemAt(stockSymbol, index);

        if(count == 0) // if 1st stock added, display
        {
            jcbStockList.setSelectedItem(jcbStockList.getItemAt(0));
            jtfStockSymbol.setText((String)jcbStockList.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }
}

private void delFromStockList(String stockSymbol)
{
    int count = jcbStockList.getItemCount();
    int index = 0;

    if(stockInList(stockSymbol))
    {
        delStock(stockSymbol);
        jcbStockList.removeItem(stockSymbol);
    }
}

private void addToUserStocks(String userID, String stockSymbol)
                throws SQLException,IOException,ClassNotFoundException
{
    if(!stockInList(stockSymbol))
       db.addUserStocks(userID,stockSymbol);
    addToStockList(stockSymbol);
}

private void buildStockList()
{
    ArrayList rs;
    String userID = user.getUserID();

    try {
        rs = db.listUserStocks(userID);
        for(int i=0; i < rs.size(); ++i)
            addToStockList((String)rs.get(i));
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
    catch(IOException ex) {}
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    ex.getMessage(),
                    "SQL Exception Message",
                    ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
    }
    jcbStockList.setSelectedItem(jcbStockList.getItemAt(0));
    jtfStockSymbol.setText( (String)jcbStockList.getSelectedItem());
}

private void addStock(String stockSymbol)
{
    String stockDesc = null;

    String userID = user.getUserID();

    try
    {
        stockDesc = db.getStockDesc(stockSymbol);

        if(stockDesc == null) // stock not in DB
        {
            stockDesc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            "Stock not in Database. Please enter stock description");
            if(stockDesc != null)
               db.addStock(stockSymbol,stockDesc);
        }
        if(stockDesc != null)
            addToUserStocks(userID, stockSymbol);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
    catch(IOException ex) {}
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    ex.getMessage(),
                    "SQL Exception Message",
                    ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
    }
}

private void delStock(String stockSymbol)
{
    String userID = user.getUserID();

    try
    {
        db.delUserStocks(userID, stockSymbol);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
    catch(IOException ex) {}
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    ex.getMessage(),
                    "SQL Exception Message",
                    ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
    }
}

public void activate()
{
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == jbtLogout)
    {
        logoutUser();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jbtAddStock)
    {
        stockSymbol = jtfStockSymbol.getText();
        if(stockSymbol.equals(""))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "Please enter a stock ticket symbol",
                "Missing stock symbol",
                ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
        else
        {
            stockSymbol.trim(); // remove any leading, trailing whitespace
            addStock(stockSymbol.toUpperCase());
            jtfStockSymbol.setText("");
        }
        jtfStockSymbol.requestFocus();

    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jbtDelStock)
    {
        stockSymbol = jtfStockSymbol.getText();
        if(stockSymbol.equals(""))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "Please enter a stock ticket symbol",
                "Missing stock symbol",
                ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
        else
        {
            stockSymbol.trim(); // remove any leading, trailing whitespace
            if(stockInList(stockSymbol))
                delFromStockList(stockSymbol);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    "Stock ticket symbol not in list",
                    "Invalid stock symbol",
                    ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
        }
        jtfStockSymbol.setText("");
        jtfStockSymbol.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jcbStockList)
    {
        stockSymbol = (String)jcbStockList.getSelectedItem();
        jtfStockSymbol.setText(stockSymbol);
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jbtAddUser)
    {
        // userMaint(add);
        try
        {
            UserMaintFrame f = new UserMaintFrame(null, ADDUSER, db, this); // do an Add
            setVisible(false);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){}
        catch(SQLException ex) {}
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jbtUpdUser)
    {
        String userID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                            "Please input ID of user to update",
                            "Enter User ID",
                            QUESTION_MESSAGE);          // updated for v5.0
        if(userID != null)
        {
            try
            {
                User updUser = db.getUser(userID); // read user from DB
                if(updUser != null)
                {   // do an Update
                    UserMaintFrame um = new UserMaintFrame(updUser, UPDUSER, db, this);
                    setVisible(false);
                    um.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        "Please enter a valid user ID",
                        "Invalid User ID",
                        ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){}
            catch(IOException ex){}
            catch(SQLException ex) {}
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jbtDelUser)
    {
        String userID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                            "Please input ID of user to delete",
                            "Enter User ID",
                            QUESTION_MESSAGE);          // updated for v5.0
        if(userID != null)
        {
            try
            {
                User delUser = db.getUser(userID);
                if(delUser != null)
                {   // do a Delete
                    UserMaintFrame um = new UserMaintFrame(delUser, DELUSER, db, this);
                    setVisible(false);
                    um.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        "Invalid User ID",
                        "Please enter a valid user ID",
                        ERROR_MESSAGE);         // updated for v5.0
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){}
            catch(IOException ex){}
            catch(SQLException ex) {}
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == jbtListUsers)
    {
        try
        {
            UserMaintFrame um = new UserMaintFrame(null, LISTUSERS, db, this); // do list
            setVisible(false);
            um.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){}
        catch(SQLException ex) {}
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please choose a valid action.");
    }
}

private void logoutUser()
{
  this.setVisible(false);
  dispose();
  caller.activate();    // call activate method of caller object
}

// Handler for window opened event
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event)
{
    jtfStockSymbol.setText("");
    jtfStockSymbol.requestFocus();
}
// Handler for window closing event
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event)
{
  logoutUser();
}
// Handler for window closed event
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event)
{
}
// Handler for window iconified event
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent event)
{
}
// Handler for window deiconified event
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent event)
{
}
// Handler for window activated event
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event)
{
}
// Handler for window deactivated event
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent event)
{
}
}
```

I did manage to find this on another forum but it doesn't run. I don't know how to get it to point to the database. I am using Textpad.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


public class UserQuery
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
    //String userID;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String symbol;
    String name;

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:StockTracker";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    //Headings etc
    System.out.println("Stock holdings by user\n");
    System.out.println("User ID  User Name\n         Stock - Description");
    System.out.println("-------- ---------------------------");

    //Retrieve data
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users u,UserStocks us,Stocks s WHERE us.userID = u.userID AND s.symbol = us.symbol ");

    String lastUserId = null;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        String userID = rs.getString("userID");
        if (userID.equals(lastUserId))
        {
            System.out.print("\t\t\t");
        } else

        {
            System.out.print(userID + "\t" + rs.getString("firstName") + "\t" + rs.getString("lastName") +"\t");
            lastUserId = userID;
        }
        System.out.println("\t" + rs.getString("symbol") + "\t" + rs.getString("name"));
    }
    System.out.println("Report done.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: If you want help, you will need to improve your Question.  1) You dumped a couple of hundred lines of code ... and people are unlikely to plough through that much.  2) You didn't bother to tell us what isn't working.  3) You don't appear to have *attempted* to implement `StockTrackerDb`.

Comment: It's not about it not working so much as me not knowing how to do it.I left the database in case it would help at all. I'm not really sure how to implement the database.

Comment: In that case, I suggest that you read the Oracle / Java tutorial on JDBC.  And if you don't know SQL read a tutorial on that.  StackOverflow is for specific questions ...